# AngularJS Providers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm studying providers in AngularJS but I am a beginner in AngularJS and not very experienced in javascript.
I was looking in AngularStrap code and found that the modal provider (src\modal\modal.js) returns a function instead of an object:

```
this.$get = function($window, $rootScope, $bsCompiler, $animate, $timeout, $sce, dimensions) {

    ...

    return ModalFactory;
};
```

Why is the function  returned instead of the concrete object.
In my understanding, in this case, the service can't act like a singleton, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular service instances can be [anything](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#conclusion) (except `service` service because it uses constructor function to create an object with `new`).

The value returned by `$get` is saved as service instance when the service is being injected the first time. This instance is returned during all subsequent dependency injections within the same app, `$get` won't be called again, that is why the services are singletons.

Answer (score 1):

Because factories are just function that return an object.

form angularJS code :

```
function factory(name, factoryFn) { 
    return provider(name, { $get: factoryFn }); //<------ juste called, not newed.
}

function service(name, constructor) {
    return factory(name, ['$injector', function($injector) {
      return $injector.instantiate(constructor);
    }]);
}
```

Comment: but in this case if I inject the $modal in my controller for example, it won't be an object, it will otherwise return an object if I call $modal(arguments), but isn't a service suposed to be a singleton object?

Comment: @MarcoPrado `$modal` function itself is a singleton, not the value it returns. `$modal` dependency injected in one place will be `===` equal to `$modal` dependency injected in other app parts. Doing `$modal.fnProperty = ...` once will cause `$modal` function to have this property everywhere else.

Comment: @estus now it's clear to me, I thought the service should be used as an single object itself, and not to instantiate new objects. Thank you